# Google Directions API -- get XML response without HTML markup

Tags: html, android, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an Android app and using Google Maps and Directions API. I was able to successfully get directions in XML for all supported modes. However, they all come back with HTML markup. 
Does anyone know if there is a way to omit the markup when making a request, so that I don't have to remove it locally in the app?
(Example: 1. "Turn right on **Broad St.**" and so on, is what I currently receive. But of course, the word is not bold, but you can actually see the tags).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be pretty easy to do with RegEx:

`String directions = htmlDirections.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");`